# What about split cones?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

Let $D : I \to C$ be a diagram in a category $C$ (i.e. $D$ is a functor and $I$ is small), $x \in C$ and $x \to D$ a [cone](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cone#cones_over_a_diagram_18) in $C$. Is there a notion of a *split cone*? If $x \to D$ is a split cone, then $x \to D$ should be an absolute limit cone, i.e. for every functor $F : C \to C'$ the cone $F(x) \to F \circ D$ is a limit cone in $C'$ (but not vice versa). The idea behind this notion should be that only some equations have to be checked, instead of checking a universal property for *all* test objects in $C$.

This should generalize the notion of a [split fork](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/split+equalizer), which is the case $I = \bullet ~ {\longrightarrow\atop\longrightarrow}\bullet$. I am also interested in special cases of $I$. For example, when $I$ is finite and discrete, we have - at least for $\mathsf{Ab}$-enriched categories - the notion of a [biproduct](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/biproduct): A diagram $\{P \xrightarrow{p_n} A_n\}_{n \in I}$ is a biproduct if there are morphisms $i_n : A_n \to P$ satisfying $p_n i_m = \delta_{n,m} \mathrm{id}$ and $\sum_n i_n p_n = \mathrm{id}$.

Comment: There is a notion of absolute limit, but I don't think these are always split in quite the sense you suggest.

Comment: I know that and this is also included in my question.

Comment: Huh, apparently I was mistaken. See the fourth bullet point [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/absolute+colimit#particular_absolute_colimits_15).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered a while ago ;) by Zhen Lin in the comments.

The condition for a cone $u : x \to D$ to be "split" (and this is actually equivalent to being absolute) is the following: There exists $i_0 \in I$ and $v : D(i_0) \to x$ such that $v \circ u_{i_0} = \mathrm{id}_x$ and for every $i \in I$ the morphisms $u_i \circ v : D(i_0) \to D(i)$ and $\mathrm{id}_{D(i)} : D(i) \to D(i)$ lie in the same connected component inside of the comma category $D \,/\, D(i)$.